# Creating symbols between connecting lines to represent line boundaries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hydrology, waterways

[image: assessment unit boundaries]

I am trying to figure out a way to create markers as seen from the attached image where an angled line (in dark red) is created between the lines to represent a connecting stream. With the data I am using, each break is actually an assessment unit and all assessment units form a segment (stream). Does anyone know how these are created? I would assume an "end of line" symbol" but not sure where to look for that.

I am using ArcMap 10.6 and have access to most all tools.

Comment: Are you lines in a single feature class? Does each category (1502_03, 1501_01, etc) have a single feature or multiple features associated with it? What type of coordinate systems does your data use?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a separate point layer and add points at each desired location where you would like the marker. With that, you could utilize the layer's character marker to customize a marker to your preference.

[image: Point Layer Character Marker]

From here, add a new field to the point layer and record the line segment's endpoint angle.

[image: Line Segment Angle]

With the angles stored in the point layer's attributes, go into the point layer's symbology properties, select advanced, rotation and set the option to the angle field you created.

[image: Point Layer Rotation]

You may need to add negatives depending on the selected settings and/or angle but the result should something like this.

[image: Line Segment Endpoint Marker]